# How to get size of a loaded icon in c++ winapi

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

i have loaded an icon `("c:\test.ico")` using `LoadImage()` function
how can i get the size of this icon? (number of bytes in it)
i am using c++ & winapi

```
HRSRC hRes = LoadImage ( NULL, icon, IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );
LPVOID lpResLock = LockResource(hRes);
```

(more precisely, size of data pointed to by "lpResLock")

========update======
i know about `sizeofresource()` But the problem is, its to load resource from an executable files. As i shown in my question, i am loading a standalone- local resource from disk file. Second issue is, the `hResInfo` parameter must have to be created using `FindResource` function, in my case i am using `LoadImage()`.. So this cant be of help

Comment: Would the layout of each resource within the .res (and .exe compulsory) help at all? MS did a pretty good job documenting them all  starting with [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007(v=vs.85).aspx). The [ICO file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) in conjunction with that can probably get you what you're looking for.

Comment: LoadImage returns an HICON. It does not return HRSRC. Which means that the entire premise of your question is wrong.

Comment: @David Heffernan  --- Thats not correct david hefferman.. LoadImage() return type is documented as ''HANDLE''. It just returns the handle to loaded image, may be its icon/bmp/cursor. (not necessarily always an icon, as you imagined it!) Its a general purpose function to load images, just like name says). Internally HRSRC, HICON, HANDLE etc are all same data type - all just handles.

Comment: @WhozCraig. thanks for the links. Have been through

Comment: Your code returns an HICON. Because you passed IMAGE_ICON. HICON and HRSRC are not assignment compatible. I am very familiar with the polymorphic nature of HANDLE. I am also familiar with LoadImage.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, its good that you are familiar with everything. However, i am compelled again to point out that you are again saying wrong facts.  HICON and HRSRC are compatible.. just open a win32 project in your VS and try it yourself. You simply need a caste (HRSRC), and it will compile and run happily. I am pasting the windows datatypes documnetaion page so that you can read it and get rid of your confusion about windows data types. Please read this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please note the following definitions in that page.. and you can see what all these WIDNOWS derived datatypes actually get transfered to internally...typedef HANDLE HRSRC;
typedef HANDLE HRGN;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
typedef HANDLE HICON;               
            HICON, HRSRC even HWND all are HANDLE.. also remember what petzold said "everything in windows is a handle". I hope now you have got rid of your confusion.. If you are still doubting, open your visual studio and try to assign an HICON to HRSRC, if you fail, i will show you that it will work through a video

Comment: Whilst your compiler allows you to cast any HBITMAP, HICON, HRSRC, etc. to a variable of different type, that doesn't mean that the code will do anything useful. I am also familiar with that topic. You are interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: Just step back and think about what you are saying. Your argument would lead to the conclusion that a HANDLE returned by create file can be cast to HBITMAP and then be passed to functions that operate on bitmaps. Or cast to HWND and now, hey presto, we've got a window by calling CreateFile.

Comment: @davidhefferman    . No.. a handle of a bitmap is ofcourse not same as handle to hwnd. It would obviously be stupid to even think that.. But I am just saying that, (1)what you said about "its not possible to assign an HICON to HRSRC" is not correct.. It can be done..  and (2) LoadImage doesnt always return HICON  (3)internally all these handles are stored in same manner. Its upto the programmer (or compiler) to make the distinction

Comment: LoadImage doesn't always return HICON. It depends on the parameters you pass. Your code passes IMAGE_ICON. So your code always returns HICON. HICON is a handle to an icon. HRSRC is a handle to a resource. They aren't the same and they are not assignment compatible. You could easily confirm this. For example try a call to FindResource followed by a call to GetIconInfo. It's strange that your mind is so closed. I can't imagine how you can learn anything with your attitude.

Comment: The return type is declared as HANDLE because the return value is polymorphic. It can be HICON, HCURSOR or HBITMAP. And there is no type that expresses that polymorphism. But the object returned when you pass IMAGE_ICON is always HICON. Sure it's declared to have type HANDLE, but that's the compile time type. The runtime type is HICON. Or if you pass IMAGE_BITMAP the runtime type would be HBITMAP. I don't want to prove anything. I'm honestly trying to help you.

Comment: Arguing about what pointer types are compatible with which other pointer types in a sub-C API is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Google for `SizeofResource()`. Its a standard win32 API function IIRC

This is the function prototype:

```
DWORD WINAPI SizeofResource(
  _In_opt_  HMODULE hModule,
  _In_      HRSRC hResInfo
);
```

Parameters:

> hModule [in, optional] Type: HMODULE
>        A handle to the module whose executable file contains the resource.
>
> hResInfo [in] Type: HRSRC
>        A handle to the resource. This handle must be created by using the FindResource or FindResourceEx function.

### Update-

Then, the length of resource from a file = sizeof the file.

use: `GetFileLength()` function coded like this:

```
DWORD GetFileLength(LPSTR fileName)
{
   DWORD len = 0;
   OFSTRUCT of;
   HFILE hFile = OpenFile(fileName,&of, OF_READ);
   GetFileSize(hFile,&len);
   CloseHandle(hFile);
   return len;
}
```

Comment: ya i know about sizeofresource().. But the problem is, its to load resource from an executable file. As i shown in my question, i am loading a standalone- local resource from disk file. Second issue is, the hResInfo parameter must have to be created using FindResource function, in my case i am using LoadImage().. So this cant be of help

Comment: Also, this is not correct (part2). [GetFileSize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955(v=vs.85).aspx) **returns** the low dword of the 64-bit file length. The high dword is returned in the out param. You should be returning the result of the function; not the value in the out-param (which is optional anyway if the file is known to be smaller tha 4gB).

Comment: GetFileAttributesEx is probably the easiest way to get the size of a file.

Comment: @David Heffernan, thats not correct. Because using ''GetFileAttributeEx'' is like using a bulldozer to kill a fly. You have to pass enumeration and structure and in the end, you retrieve the file size as two DWORDS just like in ''GetFileSize()''. And ''GetFileAttributesEX'' retrieves other file-info as well, causing overhead. Why beat the bush with overhead, when there is the simple ''GetiFileSize()'' function created solely for the purpose of getting filesize? I am down voting your comment for wrong info

Comment: Are you sure? GetFileSize needs a file handle. So you have to open the file in order to call it. On the other hand, the GetFileAttributesEx approach, or FindFirstFile, can get the info from meta data which is less heavy. Raymond Chen discussed this not so long ago.

Comment: Here's Raymond's article in case you are interested: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/23/5612082.aspx

Comment: Nice article but still, using GetFileSize() is simpler than GetFileAttributeEx()..  Getting a filehandle is not a tedious task. I have up-voted for your previous comment.

Comment: Hardly. GetFileSize requires 3 API calls vs 1 the other way. And each API call needs error handling. And not only is my way simpler, it's quicker too.

Comment: In my case, i can get filesize in 2 API calls.. in simplest form, one CreateFile() followed by a GetFileSize().. This seems simple enough for me. If you think using GetFileAttributeEx() is simpler, you may try it with all those enumeration and structures as its parameters. It may be just one API call, but we are talking about easiest method here. Each to his own

Comment: It has one enum and one struct. The enum is declared in the Windows header file. The struct likewise. Your 2 API call leaks the handle by failing to call CloseHandle. Don't do that. Call CloseHandle.